# How to communicate two devices with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm developing an flutter app that is about two people: who asks for a service (**customer**) and who accepts that service (**worker**).

The customer can select any worker he wants clicking on "Seleccionar" button[you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ferf.png) when press on that button appears a two minutes timer and the app sends service information to worker and he can see that service information and decide whether to accept or not the service. if he accept I want the following to happen on the client's screen: Redirect to another screen y show a dialog but only if the worker accepts the service.

I think i explain myself well if not let me know

If it helps im working with riverpod and firebase auth and firestore.

What have i tried?

I tried with a custom riverpod state, called **"confirmacionProveedorProvider"** (Proveedor is the worker) i switch to true in "Aceptar Servicio" [you can se here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcUB3.png) in worker screen once he sees the service information. In the console print what i expected to happen (true) but it doesnt what it do

In the customer screen I have the following code:

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3RZK.png)

Keep in mind that they are two different phones and I think because of that my solution doesn't work